# PostgreSQL GIN index for BIGINT column

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

I have table `tbl` with columns
- data TEXT
- fk_id BIGINT
- text TEXT

There is over 100M records, and ~1K different values for fk_id.
I need to run query like this

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE fk_id=12345 AND text LIKE '%abcdef%`

I tried to use extension `GIN` index with `btree_gin` and `gin_trgm_ops`

`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;`
`CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;`

`CREATE INDEX on tbl USING GIN (fk_id, text gin_trgm_ops)`

But query analyzer ignore column `fk_id` for query

`explain select * from tbl where fk_id = 12345 and text like '%abcdef%' limit 10;`

```
Limit  (cost=28.00..32.02 rows=1 width=90)
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl  (cost=28.00..32.02 rows=1 width=90)
        Recheck Cond: (text ~~ '%abcdef%'::text)
        Filter: (fk_id = 12345)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table_fk_id_text_idx  (cost=0.00..28.00 rows=1 width=0)
              Index Cond: (text ~~ '%abcdef%'::text)
```

But if I use INT type instead of BIGINT for column fk_id, index will work as I expect

`tbl` 
- data TEXT
- fk_id INT
- text TEXT

`explain select * from tbl where fk_id = 12345 and text like '%abcdef%' limit 10;`

```
Limit  (cost=36.00..40.02 rows=1 width=90)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl  (cost=36.00..40.02 rows=1 width=90)
        Recheck Cond: ((fk_id = 12345) AND (text ~~ '%abcdef%'::text))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tbl_fk_id_text_idx  (cost=0.00..36.00 rows=1 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((fk_id = 12345) AND (text ~~ '%abcdef%'::text))
```

So, I can use GIN with INT, but cannot use GIN with BIGINT. Why I cannot use BIGINT column for GIN index?
[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/btree-gin.html) says, that btree_gin works with int4(INT) and with int8(BIGINT).
Maybe there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Encountered the same issue, found answer on DBA https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126828